# Diplay ModelForm in html

Tags: django

I am creating a webapp in which a user can create a `project`, inside each project he can answer a `set of question`(in my app, I call them `secondquestions`).

I am trying to use ModelForm to ease the creation of the form by following this guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

**Howver** I do not understand how I can display in my html my form.

**secondquestions/views.py**

```
def secondquestionstoanswer(request, project_id):
  project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = SecondquestionForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
  return render(request, 'secondquestions/secondquestionstoanswer.html', {'project':project})
```

**secondquestions/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from projects.models import Project
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

    class Secondquestion(models.Model):
        second_one = models.TextField()
        second_two = models.TextField()
        second_three = models.TextField()
        second_four = models.TextField()
        second_five = models.TextField()
        second_six = models.TextField()
        second_seven = models.TextField()
        second_eighth = models.TextField()
        second_nine = models.TextField()
        developer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        project = models.OneToOneField(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    class SecondquestionForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Secondquestion
            fields = ['second_one', 'second_two', 'second_three', 'second_four', 'second_five', 'second_six', 'second_seven', 'second_eighth', 'second_nine']
```

**secondquestions/secondquestionstoanswer.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}First set{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

**My problem:**
In my html I just see the Submit button, not the form.

Comment: You never passed the form to the context.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that my `SecondquestionForm(ModelForm)` is not sent to my `views.py` and thus the `{{form}}` in my html does not work?

Comment: do you understand what `{'project': project}` is doing at the end of your view?

Comment: My understanding is this: since I am creating a new `secondquestion` inside a `project`, I have to specify which project I am creating the form/model for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never constructed a form that you passed to the template engine.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def secondquestionstoanswer(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SecondquestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.project = project
            form.save()
            return redirect('some_view')
    else:
        form = SecondquestionForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'secondquestions/secondquestionstoanswer.html',
        {'project':project, 'form': form}
    )
```

With *`'some_view'`*, the name of the view to where you want to redirect in case the submission is successful.

In your `<form>` you specify in the `action="..."` attribute where what endpoint should be triggered, like:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'view_name_of_second_question' project.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I start to understand better. I imported on to `from .models import Project, SecondquestionForm` but I still get `NameError: name 'SecondQuestionForm' is not defined`

Comment: @Prova12: is your class properly indented? The `class SecondquestionForm` is defined at the top level?

Comment: Yes, everything is properly indented in `secondquestions/model.py` and I wrote `from .models import Project, SecondquestionForm` in `secondquestions/views.py`

Comment: Ah solved! `form = SecondQuestionForm()` should be with lower "q"-->`form = SecondquestionForm()`

Comment: Last question. The 'secondquestion' are linked both to a 'project ' and `developer`. I see that we are passing the 'project' instance, but we are not passing the `developer` one. I tried to add, in my views, `form.developer = request.user` just below `form.instance.project = project` but I am not sure if is the right approach because now in my html I can select the `developer` among all the existing ones rather than automatically select the developer who is submitting this form

Comment: @Prova12: it is `form.instance.developer = request.user`. You should exclude that field from your form. Did you by any chance added this to the `fields = [...]` in the `Meta`?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `forms.py` file that will contain your Model Form

## secondquestions/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Secondquestion

class SecondquestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Secondquestion
    fields = ['second_one', 'second_two', 'second_three', 'second_four', 'second_five', 'second_six', 'second_seven', 'second_eighth', 'second_nine']
```

Comment: But the `Form`s can be defined anywhere (well as long as these are not a dependency of the `models.py` that you are using). In fact `forms.py` is not necessary at all.